# jquery autocomplete is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have written the code below. Simply I want to get source array with ajax from userfunctions.php.. It works but after few miliseconds the selection div disappears. Also when I don't use $('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({.. in success: it doesn't even work.. It sees array empty. What can I do to solve this problem?

I am using: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

```
$('#autocomplete-ajax').keyup(function(){
    var ara = $(this).val();
    var ara= ara.replace("@", "");
    var data = "action=get_auto_users&text="+ara;
    var arr = new Array();
    $.ajax({ url: '/inc/userfunctions.php',
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            obj = JSON.parse(output);
            arr = new Array();
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                arr.push(value[2])
            });

            $('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
                lookup: arr,
                lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
                    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
                    return re.test(suggestion.value);
                },
                onHint: function (hint) {
                    $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
                }
            });

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it like below and adding focus on the bottom of callauto function is worked!

```
$('#autocomplete-ajax').keyup(function(){
    var ara = $(this).val();
    var ara= ara.replace("@", "");
    var data = "action=get_auto_users&text="+ara;
    $.ajax({ url: '/inc/userfunctions.php',
        data: data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            obj = JSON.parse(output);
            arr = new Array();
            $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                arr.push(value[2]);
            });
            callauto(arr);

        }
    });
});

function callauto(arr){
    $('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
        lookup: arr,
        lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
            var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
            return re.test(suggestion.value);
        },
        onHint: function (hint) {
            $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
        }
    });
    $('#autocomplete-ajax').focus();
}
```